# How can I eliminate a server-only dependency when porting code to browser using webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, jsdom

I have a TypeScript code that uses `jsdom` on the server side (node.js) to generate a DOM structure:

**DomCreator.ts**

```
const {JSDOM} = require('jsdom');
```

To run this code in the browser, I configured Webpack to treat `jsdom` as an external and not include it in the bundle:

**webpack.config.js**

```
externals: {
    jsdom: "jsdom"
  }
```

When the code is executed in the browser, a real DOM exists so jsdom is of no real use. However, webpack still expects `jsdom` to be separately available in the global space, due to the way externals work.

My workaround was to create a fake `jsdom` object on top of the page, so I don't run into a `jsdom is not defined` error in browser:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var  jsdom = {} ;
    jsdom.JSDOM = 0  ;
</script>
```

I have put condition in TypeScript code to check the presence of `window` object (as a proxy to being in browser environment) and create the DOM object either through `jsdom` or use native browser `document` based on this condition:

**DomCreator.ts**

```
    if(typeof window != 'undefined'){
        console.log('browser detected.');
        body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    } 
    else {
        console.log('node detected');
        body = (new JSDOM()).dom.window.document.querySelector("body") ;
    }
```

This works OK but looks patchy to me. Are there best practices for handling situations like this? In particular, I don't want to create the fake `jsdom` object in the client-side code, and also I'm not sure if checking `window` is the best way of separating the server and client side logic.

Comment: I dont know jsdom, but maybe `jsdom = document` ?

Comment: Thanks. My goal is not to have a mention of `jsdom` in the client-side code, because jsdom is not relevant to client.

Comment: If that's the goal, you'll have to write the code like that. Write a high-level functions that use jsdom or regular dom APIs.